# Negar o acesso a uma pasta com mod_rewrite pode ser inseguro?

Tags: apache, htaccess, segurança

Eu estou pensando em criar um microframework php bem limitado apenas para uso próprio, no entanto me deparei com uma situação, a maioria dos frameworks usa uma pasta chamada `public` e nos servidores geralmente de produção apontamos esta pasta com `DocumentRoot` através do `httpd.conf`.

As estruturas geralmente é assim:

```
/home/user/projeto
├── data/
├── vendor/
├── application/
└── public/
    ├── .htaccess
    └── index.php
```

O vhost é semelhante a isto:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/user/projeto/public"
    <Directory "/home/user/projeto/public">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Mas como no meu caso é um *microframework* simples para uso pessoal eu pensei em usar assim a estrutura de pastas:

```
/home/user/projeto
├── index.php
├── .htaccess
└── exemplo/
    ├── application/
    ├── vendor/
    └── data/
```

Neste segundo exemplo o `/home/user/projeto/.htaccess` esta assim:

```
IndexIgnore *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule "^exemplo/" "index.php" [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note que eu usei `RewriteRule "^exemplo/" "index.php" [L]` pra prevenir acessar a o conteúdo da pasta `exemplo/` aonde se encontra os arquivos do projeto, bibliotecas e classes e a pasta `data/` que é usada para gravar dados não publicos. Também caso seja acessado assim: `http://site/exemplo/` ele irá executar o `/home/user/projeto/index.php`.

O motivo de querer usar a segunda maneira, é poder facilitar portar a aplicação para outros servidores sem precisar configurar o `DocumentRoot` e reiniciar o Apache, tornando as configurações mais fáceis.

A pergunta é:

- Usar `RewriteRule "^exemplo/" "index.php" [L]` para impedir o acesso a pasta `exemplo/` aonde tenho as pastas `data/`, `vendor/` e `application/` pode ser inseguro ou pode causar algum outro tipo de problema?

Comment: Eu parei de responder porque fiquei meio confuso, e apesar de não haver problemas de segurança visualmente, sinto que algo me está a escapar, porque do jeito que está o usuário já está praticamente no directório  `exemplo` entendes ? Ele basicamente já possui acesso a esse directório pelo simples facto dele estar no directório público, a única coisa que separa ele do resto é o redirect que é accionado caso seja acessado.

Comment: Não seria o mesmo que colocar vários ficheiros `index.php` com `header(location)` no directório `exemplo` e nos que sucedem este ?

Comment: Olha, desactiva todos os `.htaccess` existentes e cria um ficheiro `index,php` na pasta `exemplo` com `header("location:../"); exit();`, e testa.

Comment: @Edilson eu sei como o uso de `header("location:../"); exit();` ou `header("", true, 403); exit();` funciona para anular o acesso ao exemplo. Mas por favor entenda que o `RewriteRule` já anula o acesso. A questão é se usar o `RewriteRule "^exemplo/" "index.php" [L]` tem algum problema de segurança, entende?

Comment: Não seria a mesma coisa, mas é basicamente o mesmo, é isso que eu queria provar. Apesar de poder parecer conveniente, acho que seria bom se mantivesses a primeira forma, embora pareça mais trabalhosa. Ainda assim é-me vaga a ideia.

Comment: @Edilson não seria o mesmo, pois location rediriciona no browser, o rewriterule é um redirecionamento interno, ou seja é uma url reescrita. Sim é o ponto que quero chegar, porque manter a primeira forma que é mais trabalhosa? Talvez isto responda a questão :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento nao se aplica pro seu caso, pq é pra rodar em varios lugares diferentes, mas só de curiosidade: eu tenho um sistema em que o DocumentRoot é o PHP e não a pasta. Assim todo o caminho é gerenciado pelo PHP, e nem .htaccess usa. Só que passa a nao existir mais nada estático no site. nessa hora o header("X-Sendfile: $filename"); ajuda a nao sobrecarregar o PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente usa-se a técnica de verificação de uma constante.

Desse modo como vc mostrou é muito interessante pois deixa o código limpo e livre da gambiarra da técnica da constante.

A portabilidade disso vai depender de como traduzir essa regra do `mod_rewrite` para outros servidores como o *Nginx* e *IIS*. Mas não é difícil.

Quanto a efeitos colaterais ou questões de segurança, não há como o usuário ter acesso desde que a regra esteja funcionando.

Algo que pode acarretar em problemas é o fato de usar `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`.

A utilidade disso é evitar que ocorra erro interno quando o servidor não possuir o `mod_rewrite`.

Por outro lado, se o servidor não possuir o `mod_rewrite`, a regra não será lida e nenhum erro será disparado. Isso é um pouco perigoso pois ocorrerá de forma silenciosa deixando a pasta desprotegida.

Uma dica é, remover a condicional que verifica se o `mod_rewrite` está carregado.

Todavia, é mais fácil encontrar um servidor sem mod_rewrite do que encontrar um servidor que ofereça somente uma pasta de acesso público.

Ambos os casos podem existir num mesmo servidor. Nesse ponto, não tem muita saída a não ser usar a técnica da constante.

Comment: Realmente talvez seja este o único e principal problema, há que ter em conta o problema de reescrita aqui - `RewriteRule "^exemplo/" "index.php" [L]`

Comment: Portabilidade e estrutura sem ter que configurar internamente a toda hora, era essa a pergunta. E o porquê é simples, demasiados parágrafos tornam o texto mais curto e fácil de ler.

Comment: No pior dos casos dá pra tentar bloquear o acesso no .htaccess, ao menos se não funcionar o rewrite, a pessoa não chega a acessar a pasta. Isso se o allowoverride permitir, claro...

Comment: @Bacco então mas o `Deny` funciona antes dos módulos pois ele é Core do Apache, se  criar um .htaccess dentro da pasta exemplo eu não conseguirei criar um rota assim `http://site/exemplo/test` pois irá gerar HTTP_403, eu sei que é improvável criar uma rota com o mesmo nome da pasta, mas a ideia é deixar livre também.